# Specify a start time when resampling

Tags: python, pandas

I am resampling the following into hourly units however the result starts the hour from the top of the hour - I would like it to start from the bottom of the hour.

```
                        Open    High      Low    CLose
DateTime                                              
2014-07-25 14:30:00  1975.75  1977.0  1972.50  1976.00
2014-07-25 15:00:00  1976.00  1977.5  1974.25  1976.75
2014-07-25 15:30:00  1976.50  1977.0  1972.75  1973.50
2014-07-25 16:00:00  1973.25  1973.5  1968.00  1970.25
2014-07-25 16:30:00  1970.25  1972.5  1970.25  1971.50
```

Example:

```
ff = ff.resample('H').agg({'Open':'first', 'High':'max', 'Low':'min', 'CLose':'last'})
```

Gives me:

```
                        Open     High      Low    CLose
DateTime                                               
2014-01-08 14:00:00  1920.25  1930.00  1919.00  1928.50
2014-01-08 15:00:00  1928.75  1932.25  1922.00  1923.25
2014-01-08 16:00:00  1923.25  1923.50  1910.25  1912.00
2014-01-08 17:00:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2014-01-08 18:00:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

But I would like each row to start from 14:30 then 15:30 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the `offset` parameter, which is new in pandas since *version 1.1.0.*.

```
df.resample('H', offset='30T').agg({'Open':'first', 'High':'max', 'Low':'min', 'CLose':'last'})
```

The output in your example is

```
                        Open    High      Low    CLose
DateTime                                              
2014-07-25 14:30:00  1975.75  1977.5  1972.50  1976.75
2014-07-25 15:30:00  1976.50  1977.0  1968.00  1970.25
2014-07-25 16:30:00  1970.25  1972.5  1970.25  1971.50
```